# Fleck websocket implementation issue. Unable to use socket.Send

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, websocket, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently trying to implement **Websockets** using [**Fleck**](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck), and somewhat merging it with [this **BLE sample**](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE). 
My ultimate goal for this is to communciate received heart rate data from a BLE device to websocket, and then receive it in unity.

My issue right now is that I am unable to use the **Fleck socket.Send(message)** function inside visual studio inside the BLE sample code.

When I type it, it's underlined in red and comes up with the error that **"Reference to type 'Task' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found. "**

I'm pretty new to C#, Websockets and Visual Studio in general.

What I did was **reference the Fleck.dll** in visual studio. The only one that worked was the dll inside **Fleck/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0**, then declared the WebSocketServer etc. socket.OnOpen(), onClose() and onMessage() all work. However, it just doesn't like socket.Send.

I tried manually adding a reference to the System.Runtime.dll , however it said that the component is already automatically referenced by the build system.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It sound like you need to rebuild the sample.  It may have been build with a different version of Net that you have on your PC.  I would first check the timestamp of the exe file for the sample.  It is in the bin folder of the project.  You also must start the service before running the sample.  I did not get a chance to look at sample code so I'm not sure how the service gets started.

Comment: @jdweng I tried rebuilding the sample to no avail. What do you mean by start the service before running the sample? The BLE sample works on its own, but the issue is with the Fleck websocket functions that aren't working with it :(

Comment: I have a feeling this is because fleck targets NET4.0, and my BLE Sample perhaps doesn’t use that framework? I’m quite new to all this , but how would I change the framework being used in the BLE sample?

Comment: Did the exe file get generated after you did a build?  Check the date of the exe.  If the file got updated then you project is working with the sample.  The code doesn't work on its own if you need both the websocket and the sample to run.  You have two side of a connection (client and server).  The Server must get started first so that is what I would attempt to get working first.  The link you provided as two paragraphs : 1) Client 2) Server.  You must get the Server paragraph working first.

Comment: @jdweng yep the BLE sample exe updates if I just rebuild the original BLE sample without changing any code. But that’s not my problem here - I am trying to use WebSockets with the BLE sample. I’m adding code into the .cs files in the BLE Sample and The issue is that when I’m writing the code, visual studio doesn’t like me using socket.Send(message) and throws the error I stated in my original question - so I wouldn’t even be able to build it because there’s an error! (Also the BLE app is intended to be the server side)

Comment: The send gives an error when the Receive mode is in Asynchronous mode and you try to use Synchronous Send.  So you have to use Asynchronous Send.  See the msdn samples : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples.  The samples use sockets, but you can use any class that inherits the socket like TcpClient or TcpListener.   Just replace sockets with appropriate client or listener.

Comment: The server cannot send until the client connects.  The client is the master and the server the slave.  You start the server first and wait for a connection from a client.  The client send the first message and the server responds.

Comment: I think maybe there's a miscommunication of the problem at hand right now - to clarify, I am using the Fleck implementation of websockets in c# . The usual declaration of the websocketserver, functions socket.onOpen() and onClose() etc. work fine but when i type the socket.send() function FROM the fleck implementation, visual studio underlines it in red and says there's an error. This is not an error when I'm trying to run the sample, or build it, it's before all of that. I am just trying to write the code required haha

Comment: You cannot send until the sample client connects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Fixed it by just updating the NET core universal windows platform in Nuget Package Manager inside Visual Studio. It was using an outdated version.